# What are the "modified" and "standby" RAM regions in Resource Monitor?

Tags: memory, resource-monitor

[image: a screen shot from resource monitor]

The "Resource Monitor" tool of Windows 7 shows me a typical memory map like in the screen shot above. What are the orange colored *modifed* and blue colored *standby* regions in this graphic? What exactly are their functions?

Answer (score 18):

The "Modified" region, logically enough, holds data that has been modified. This can include data that needs to be written to disk. It can also include private mappings that have been modified that don't need to be written to disk.

The "Standby" region contains information that may be used later but can also just be thrown away. It is thus standing by to be used immediately for a more important purpose should one come along. It may include pages that have been pre-zeroed so they can be used without having to fill them with zeroes. It can include pages that hold contents of files on disk that could be used to avoid having to read the files again.

[RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) can break these regions down for you so you can see what they're really doing.

Comment: I have a server where about 50% of the ram is "Modified" i wish that i could get more information about it without installing a additional program (Not something I'm going to do on a production server).
Its not a problem is just curious what is going on.

Comment: Monitoring software *definitely* belongs on production machines (after testing that the software doesn't interfere on non-production machines, of course).

Answer (score 14):

> **Standby:** Pages of physical ram not actively being used. These are still left in physical ram but will be repurposed first by the memory
>   manager (either returned to the active list or zeroed out and reused)
>   if something needs physical ram for active pages. **Standby pages are
>   essentially cache – it’s better to have infrequently used data kept in
>   RAM “just in case” than pushing it out to disk when the memory isn’t
>   needed for anything else.**
>
> **Modified:** Similar to Standby, but these are pages of physical RAM that have been changed and must be flushed to disk before reusing
>   them.

**Source:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap